# Julian day with this format : AAAJJJ

Tags: php, converters, schedule, julian-date, georgian

i have this date :
**28 september 2007.**

I need this output : **007271**

I'm using this code :

```
<?php 
  $julianDate = gregoriantojd(9, 28, 2007); 

  $dayfrac = date('G') / 24 - .5; 
  if ($dayfrac < 0) $dayfrac += 1; 

  $frac = $dayfrac + (date('i') + date('s') / 60) / 60 / 24; 

  $julianDate = $julianDate + $frac; 
  echo($julianDate); 
?>
```

My current output : **2454372.81824**

I search on google and I found this website :

> http://pgj.pagesperso-orange.fr/Calendrier_conversion.htm

When I try his tool with my date the output is :

"Jour Julien  : 2454371.5"
**AND** "Jour : 271 Année : 2007"

How can I complete this task? I don't know how to find the number of the day so I can concatenate it with the year so : AAA . JJJ

Thanks alot.

Comment: `date('z', $mydate)` might help

Comment: Note that Julian Day is the number of days since midday on January 1, 4713 BC; so what you're after isn't actually the Julian Day

Comment: I found my answer ... 28 septembre is the 271 days from the 01 january ... thanks ... for your comment Mark Baker, it help me alot to figure this out ! :)

Comment: what denotes A and J. Normal A denotes AM or PM

Answer (score 0):

> the 28 septembre is the 271 days from the begin of the year 01 January ...

Comment: $dayNumber = date("z") + 1;
$year = substr(date("Y"),1,4);
$myanswer = $year.$dayNumber;

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to identify

```
<?php 

$date = strtotime('28 september 2007');

$date1 = strtotime('01 january 2007');

//this may helps
echo round(($date - $date1)/(60*60*24));

?>
```

Comment: complicated and unnecessary